# How to run explicit test cases of Nunit

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, nunit-console

My test suite project contains some explicit test cases, now i want to execute the test cases with the help of `Nunit-console.exe`. When I execute the test cases, the explicit test cases were excluded from the execution. So, I have tried to execute the test cases using the batch file in the following manner.

```
nunit-console.exe test1.dll
nunit-console.exe test1.dll /include:Expicit
```

I am executing the above 2 commands with the help of batch file.But i am not able to execute the explicit test cases.

Could you please let me know how to execute explicit test cases with the help of `nunit-console.exe`

Comment: You should probably add the nunit tag to this question.

Comment: You might consider a Category instead. /include and /exclude work well with categories. That will remove some of the protection Explicit gives you. For example if you run all tests the ones with categories will be included by default. But if you are looking to be able to just run all the tests without a certain group then Category might be a better bet.

Answer (score 7):

[Explicit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=explicit&r=2.2.10) tests can only be run with nunit-console if you name the test or test fixture on the command line, using the /fixture option.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: /include:Exp"l"icit... perhaps this is the cause?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

First, follow this answer in [When running NUnit and specifying a category, can all uncategorized tests be included too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791088/when-running-nunit-and-specifying-a-category-can-all-uncategorized-tests-be-inc) to add a [Category] to the assembly.

Then, where [Explicit] is used, add the same [Category].